# SABRE API working with v1.8.6 but not with v3.0.0

Tags: sabre

I'm facing an issue with *sabre* api *bargain max finder*.

Kindly check the things I have used  below request code:

```html
private function getRequest($origin, $destination, $departureDate) {
        $request = '{
            "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
  "OriginDestinationInformation": [
   {
                            "DepartureDateTime": "'.$departureDate.'T00:00:00",
                            "DestinationLocation": {
    "LocationCode": "'.$destination.
                            '"},
                            "OriginLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "'.$origin.
                            '"},
                            "RPH":"1"
   }
  ],
  "POS": {
                    "Source": [
                        {
                            "RequestorID": {
                                "CompanyName": {
                                    "Code": "TN"
    },
    "ID": "REQ.ID",
    "Type": "0.AAA.X"
                            }
   }
                    ]
  },
  "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                        "RequestType": {
                            "Name": "50ITINS"
   }
                    }
  },
  "TravelerInfoSummary": {
                    "AirTravelerAvail": [
                        {
                            "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                                {
                                    "Code": "ADT",
                                    "Quantity": 1
    }
                            ]
   }
                    ]
  }
            }

        }';
        return $request;
    }
```

When I'am using above request code **it's working fine**  with version *1.8.6* api but **not working** with version *3.0.0*

Kindly Help me out.

Comment: When you say that it is not working, are you getting an error? If yes, what error are you getting? Is this calling the REST or SOAP version of BFM?

Comment: its working fine now i have debugged it easily brian thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and posted a question on it here: [Sabre Bargain Finder Max REST API IF2 Schedule Error in v3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353734/sabre-bargain-finder-max-rest-api-if2-schedule-error-in-v3-0-0)

The correct answer (that worked for me) was: change the PseudoCityCode.