# Sabre Bargain Finder Max REST API IF2 Schedule Error in v3.0.0

Tags: rest, sabre

I am working with SabreDev REST API for Bargain Finder Max (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max). When I run the example they provide in version 3.0.0, I get the following error:

"DSF server returned an error: Generic exception Schedule error : EA market not found - check user and owner."

The error type is "IF2". I'm still getting a 200 OK response from the server, but the content of the response is the DSF error.

The endpoint that I'm using is https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v3.0.0/shop/flights?mode=live for the Sandbox.

When I run the sample in through version 1.8.6, my code works; but v3.0.0 fails.

I know this is related to stack question 42025310 but I don't have any street cred to respond there apparently.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is usually related to using an invalid PCC or "PseudoCityCode".

If you are a Sabre subscriber and have a valid PCC, go ahead and contact the helpdesk so they can take a look.

If not, you could use the test PCC that is available in the API Explorer: https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs.